# WCF ServiceHost BaseAddresses does not contain all IIS host header values, when multiple Host Headers set in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, iis-6

I have a WCF service that has bee working for a long time, hosted in IIS6 (Windows Web Server 2003).

I am trying to add a 2nd host header value in IIS (previously there was only 1).

So now in IIS, lets say I have configured:

```
IP: All Available, Port: 80, Host: x.test.com
IP: All Available, Port: 80, Host: y.test.com
```

In my application, I have this WCF config property set:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

And I have a custom `ServiceHostFactory`:

```
public class MySuperServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In the parameter `Uri[] baseAddresses`, WCF seems to only ever pass me whatever the *first* value is in the IIS configuration. So for this example, `baseAddresses` is a `Uri[1]` with the one value `http://x.test.com/MyService.svc`.

---

The same thing happens if I specify HTTP *and* HTTPS host headers in IIS. So back to the same example, lets say for HTTP traffic we set:

```
IP: All Available, Port: 80, Host: x.test.com
IP: All Available, Port: 80, Host: y.test.com
```

And for SSL traffic we run the command:

> cscript.exe c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set /w3svc/12345/SecureBindings ":443:secureA.test.com" ":443:secureB.test.com"

So now my site should have 4 possible addresses.

However now WCF just passes me the *first* host from each *type* of connection, so my `Uri[]` now contains 2 elements:

```
http://x.test.com/MyService.svc
https://secureA.test.com/MyService.svc
```

Anyone have any insight as to why this happens?

---

**Edit:**

This link "[How can WCF support multiple IIS Binding specified per site ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rampo/archive/2008/02/11/how-can-wcf-support-multiple-iis-binding-specified-per-site.aspx)" at the very bottom says:

> **Solution in .Net Fx4.0: BaseAddressPrefixFilters**
>
> **Beta2 Fix**
>
> In the current  Beta2 release of the .NET Framework, we added  support
>   for multiple site binding  . Just set the binding in IIS site and the
>   service will inherit the address
>
> **Final RTM Fix**
>
> In the final bits, we decided to make it an opt-in due to application
>   compatability reasons. In order to enable multiple site binding, you
>   need to set multipleSiteBindingEnabled to true in your application.
>   Multiple site binding is supported only for Http protocol. The address
>   of endpoints in the configuration file need to be complete URI. When
>   porting your 3.0 or 3.5 workaround to 4.0 you need to keep this
>   particular aspect.
>
> ```
> <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
> ```

That very last bit is what I am doing. I am using .NET4's added ability to set multiple host headers in IIS, with `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"` set in my configuration.

This actually works fine if you leave the rest of WCF alone and let it do its default thing for constructing the service endpoints.

However, my issue is that all the multiple host headers aren't actually passed in to a custom `ServiceHostFactory` implementation, so it seems difficult or impossible to manually set up your own endpoints on all base addresses.

Perhaps this is just a bug in .NET 4?

Comment: Can i see your app.config please

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422401/wcf-and-multiple-host-headers) help at all?

Comment: my web.config is practically empty, it is all configured in code instead. what I have is very similar to @struhtanov's answer in your link, except that in his answer he is hard-coding in the 2 separate base addresses. I was trying to use the ones given to be my IIS, which is not the full list.

Comment: I added some more info to my original post. see the "edit" section.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom classes are you manually adding the other end points? I do believe the way it is engineered you need to do so manually...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

With this notion it seems that if the EndPoint it is the config then it will be added for you. Since your config is empty you must add the endpoint's manually.

See [WCF Self Host Service - Endpoints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807525/wcf-self-host-service-endpoints-in-c-sharp)